# Toast in PreferenceActivity is shown late

Tags: android, preferences, toast, preferenceactivity

I want to show a Toast right after the user clicks on a CheckBoxPreference in my PreferenceActivity.

```
myCheckBox.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(Prefs.this,
                        "test",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                doSomething();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I also tried to put the Toast into the doSomething() method, but it's always shown *after* the whole method is processed. I tried `getBaseContext()` instead of `Prefs.this`, but it didn't help.
Any idea why the Toast doesn't show up at once and how to make it do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the `onPreferenceClick` listener is running in the UI thread. This thread is also the same as the one that handles displaying the `Toast`. `Toast#show` only pushes a message onto the message queue that will then run code to make the `Toast` display. That queue won't be processed until after your `onPreferenceClick` handler is completely finished.

You can try:

```
myCheckBox.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(Prefs.this,
                        "test",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Prefs.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                        public void run() {
                            doSomething();
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            }
    });
```

This will cause the `Toast` to post to the message queue then your `doSomething` will also be posted to the queue after the toast. The downside to this is that there could be UI messages that will be handled before `doSomething` is called. Also, if `doSomething` is long running it will monopolize your UI thread and could cause a possible ANR force close. You may want to think about running `doSomething` in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if it takes more than 150ms or so.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this in detail.
The method is actually initiating an OAuth handshake and then starts a new activity showing a WebView to perform the OAuth authorization.
So, when the user clicks on the CheckBox, it takes some seconds before the WebView activity is started, because first a connection to Twitter is established to receive the request token. --> The reason I want to show the toast is to inform the user that something is going on in case he wanders why nothing seems to happen for some seconds (before the WebView activity is started / shown).

Comment: Show an asynctask with a progress dialog

Comment: What is Prefs.this ??

Comment: Thanks for detailing the concept. In my case, I had to replace runOnUiThread(new Runnable... with v.post(new Runnable().... RunOnUiThread will make that block to run immediately. V.post will put the block at the end of the run queue that will provide the effect desired.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is use broadcast, and make a receiver registered in android manifest.

in AndroidManifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="showtoast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

sending broadcast:

```
public static void BroadcastMessage(Context context, Bundle extra)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
    intent.setAction("showtoast");
    if (extra != null)
        intent.putExtras(extra);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

receiver like below:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if ("showtoast".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) && (bundle != null)
        {
            String title = bundle.getString("title", "");

            View view;
            TextView mTextView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_toast_layout, null);
            mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            mTextView.setText(title);

            Toast toast = new Toast(context.getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.setView(view);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```